# NERDTree with su/root access

Tags: vim, ssh, nerdtree

I came across nerdtree plugin for vim which seems to be amazing for working with files using ssh. There are many files in my `var/www/html` directory which are readonly/requires su permissions to open.

`:NERDTree` isn't working with sudo vim.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Have you tried installing the plugin for root?

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean, exactly? Also, NERDTree has nothing to do with SSH and doesn't allow you to edit files on remote machines *at all*. That feature comes with Vim in the form of the default plugin `netrw`. See `:help netrw`.

Comment: Are you using vim as root (as the title of question suggests) or as yourself with escalated privileges (as suggested by the body of the question)? NERDTree should work in the first case but you have to install it for the root user in the second case.

Comment: NerdTree isn't installed for the root user. If you want to use your configuration with sudo you can do `sudo -e` to launch your editor (Assuming `EDITOR=vim`) with user privileges and on save sudo will copy the file over with the appropriate permissions. (Or you can just install Nerdtree in root's vim configuration)

Comment: I installed Nerdtree as root as you mentioned. But its still not working.
Following message is displayed:
**E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree**